# mvc3 entity framework - convert comma separated list of strings into list<string> in viewmodel, allow users to remove items from list

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am struggling to figure out how to do this with MVC,

I have an entity framework object that has a comma separated list from the db, (can't change the fact that its a horrible csl in the db).  I can easily display the list and let them edit it manually.  This is rather error prone and would like to split them up and display a list of them in the view.  Then allow the user to click a link / button and have them removed from the string and db and the page refreshed to reflect this.

My first thought was to use JQuery to do a ajax json post to do a delete for each item the click an @Html.ActionLink for.  I could get it to do the async post back and it would delete the item and would send back a string representing the new string list which I could update the UL with.  The second time they clicked a link it would give me a 404, the script I used is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.viewSeasonsLink').click(function () {
            var data =
            {
                item: $(this).parents('li').first().find('.flagName').text(), 
                deploymentId: @Model.Id                 
            };
            $.post(this.href, data, function (result) {
                var list = $("#testme");
                list.empty();
                var items = result.split(",");
                $(items).each(function(index) {

//                  /* var link = '&quot;' +  @Html.ActionLink("Remove",     "RemoveItemFromList", "Deployment", null, new { @class = "viewSeasonsLink" }) + '&quot;';     */
                    var link = '<a class="viewSeasonsLink"     href="/SAMSite/Deployment/RemoveItemFromList">Remove</a>';

                list.append('<li><span class="flagName">' + items[index] + '</span> - ' + link + ' </li>');
                    /* list.append('<li><span class="flagName">' + items[index] + '</span> - ' + '\'' + @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "RemoveItemFromList", "Deployment", null,     new { @class = "viewSeasonsLink" }) + '\'</li>');                     */
                });                
            }, "json");
           return false;     
        });
    });
</script>
```

I could not get the action link to work with the jquery script, so tried hard coding it, still not success.

I then thought I would just try and do a simple actionlink back to a method to remove it and return the normal view, again this posts and will update the db, but will not refresh the webpage at all.

```
 <ul id="testme2">
            @foreach (string flag in ViewBag.FeatureFlags)
            {
                <li><span class="flagName">@flag</span> - @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "RemoveItemFromListTest", "Deployment", null, new { @class = "viewSeasonsLink" })</li>
            }
        </ul>

 public ActionResult RemoveItemFromListTest(string item, int deploymentId)
    {
        Deployment deployment = db.Deployments.Single(d => d.Id == deploymentId);
        ViewBag.CustomerId = new SelectList(db.Customers, "Id", "Name", deployment.CustomerId);

        List<string> featureFlags = deployment.FeatureFlags.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        featureFlags.Remove(item);

        deployment.FeatureFlags = ConvertBackToCommaList(featureFlags);
        ViewBag.FeatureFlags = featureFlags;
        //db.SaveChanges();

        return View("Edit", deployment);
    }
```

**EDIT**

released I was being a bit daft at one point:

The second test to get it to do a full post back and do the update was still getting caught by the jquery, (also was not passing in the values).  I changed the line to this:

```
<li><span class="flagName">@flag</span> - @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "RemoveItemFromListTest", "Deployment", new { item = @flag, deploymentId = Model.Id }, null)</li>
```

which does work, but is a bit naff, it would mean any changes made to the form before the remove link clicked would be lost.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see two issues. One is the initial `.Post` on the viewSeasonsList click event. You are posting back to the Action that loaded the page, not the Action that will handle the delete. I doesn't seem to me that they would be the same Action base on the approach you described.

```
var url = '/SAMSite/Deployment/RemoveItemFromList';
```

then

```
$.post(url, data, function (result) {
```

Second, in the Ajax response, when you are rebuilding the list, you are including an `href` attribute for the links. Why? you are not navigating with those links, you are initiating an Ajax request, which has already been set up.

```
var link = '<a class="viewSeasonsLink">Remove</a>';
```

Comment: Hi Steve, I have attached to the process and it will call the remove from list method each time, if that is what you are referring to in your first point.  The reason to rebuild the links was that I was emptying the UL element and then rebuilding it.  I just thought that this might be a tad backward, I could just go through and remove any element that is no longer in the list returned from the server

Comment: Yes, my post was about getting it working. You said you would get a 404 after 1 item was deleted and I think my suggestions will address this. As to your comment, I don't see a big deal with rebuilding the list. You could remove just the element clicked, I think `$(this).remove();` would do it.

Answer (score 0):

ultimately I had one main problem with the jquery solution.  When I added a new LI element it was not being hooked up to the ajax call as this was just happening at document.ready.  I now replaced the simple .click with a delegate that will also hook up all elements that are added after the ready event, [credit to this page for help with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213114/dom-not-responding-to-jquery-evers-after-load-function):

```
$('#featureflaglist').delegate('.removeflaglink', 'click', RemoveFlagFromList);
```